# Magento change shipping method according to price

Tags: magento-1.7

In magento i want to show Flatrate shipping method by default but if subtotal price is equal or greater than 100 it should show Free shipping method in cart page.

Thanks

Comment: is anyone there, please help me.

Comment: shopping cart price rule is also not working, i am tired. Please anyone can help me ?